# What are the patterns for finding Savannah animals?

Tags: disco-zoo

In Disco Zoo, you get animals by going on rescues in various areas, and each area has a few different animals (a couple common, some rare, and one mythical). Each animal will have a particular pattern in the grid of the rescue area.

The farm rescues give you the animal patterns, but the other areas don't.

For the savannah (the second area you open (the third area total)), what are the patterns for each of the animals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the patterns for Savannah:

[image]

Take a look at the [patterns of the rest of areas](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/166157/43105).