# What are the patterns for the Northern animals?

Tags: disco-zoo

Similar to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/166081/what-are-the-patterns-for-finding-savannah-animals) about the animals you rescue in the Savannah, what are the rescue patterns for the animals in the Northern area? I've noticed that the patterns get more complex with each area you open, so I'd like to minimize the chances I waste trying to find out the patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the patterns for the Northern animals:

[image]

Take a look at the [patterns of the rest of areas](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/166157/43105).