# What are the patterns for the animals in the different areas?

Tags: disco-zoo

In Disco Zoo, you get animals by going on rescues in various areas, and each area has a few different animals (a couple common, some rare, and one mythical). Each animal will have a particular pattern in the grid of the rescue area.

The farm rescues give you the animal patterns, but the other areas don't.

What are the patterns for each of the animals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### FARM ANIMAL PATTERNS

[image]
COMMON: Sheep / Pig / Rabbit
RARE: Horse / Cow
MYTHICAL: Unicorn

---

#### OUTBACK ANIMAL PATTERNS

[image]
COMMON: Crocodile / Platypus / Kangaroo
RARE: Koala / Cockatoo
MYTHICAL: Tiddilak

---

#### SAVANNA ANIMAL PATTERNS

[image]
COMMON: Zebra / Hippo / Giraffe
RARE: Lion / Elephant
MYTHICAL: Gryphon

---

#### NORTHERN ANIMAL PATTERNS

[image]
COMMON: Bear / Skunk / Beaver
RARE: Moose / Fox
MYTHICAL: Sasquatch

---

#### POLAR ANIMAL PATTERNS

[image]
COMMON: Penguin / Seal / Muskox
RARE: Polar Bear / Walrus
MYTHICAL: Yeti

---

#### JUNGLE ANIMAL PATTERNS

[image]
COMMON: Toucan / Monkey / Gorilla
RARE: Tiger / Panda
MYTHICAL: Phoenix

---

#### JURASSIC ANIMAL PATTERNS

[image]
COMMON: Diplodocus / Stegosaurus / Raptor
RARE: T-Rex / Triceratops
MYTHICAL: Dragon

---

#### ICE AGE ANIMAL PATTERNS

[image]
COMMON: Giant Sloth / Wooly Rhino / Dire Wolf
RARE: Mammoth / Saber Tooth
MYTHICAL: Ankhlut

---

Check [the source](http://www.deltaattack.com/2014/02/27/disco-zoo-guide-patterns-tips-tricks/) where you can find general tips for the game too.